# Mudar o valor do action dentro do form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho um código com um "form" e tenho dois botões que quero que direcionem para páginas diferentes.
Ao clicar no botão finalizar gostaria que o "action" seja action='envio1.php' e ao clicar no botão Alterar que o "action" seja action='envio2.php'

Obs.: Sei que é um problema bem simples, porém, sei que esse problema será resolvido com javascript e eu não entendo muito.

```html
<form method='post' action='envio1.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-5'>
      <h4 class='modal-title' style='margin-right: 140px;'></h4>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-5 text-right' style="text-decoration:none; color:white; float: right">
      <button class='btn btn-danger' name='FINALIZAR' value="OK">FINALIZAR</button>
      <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success'>ALTERAR</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: O que é valor A e valor B?

Comment: Eu vou reformular a perguntar

Comment: É bom mesmo pois é uma candidata a fechamento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode mudar o `action` do `form` no `onClick` de cada botão:

**HTML:**

```
<form id='form' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <button type='submit' id='botaoFinalizar' class='btn btn-danger' name='FINALIZAR' value="OK">FINALIZAR</button>
    <button type='submit' id='botaoEnviar' class='btn btn-success'>ALTERAR</button>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
document.getElementById('botaoFinalizar').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('form').action = '/envio1.php';
}
document.getElementById('botaoEnviar').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('form').action = '/envio2.php';
}
```

Se o formulário não for enviado, você pode usar o `.submit()` no form depois de mudar o `.action`.

---

Ou você pode usar o atributo `formaction`. Veja o [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-html_elements_button_formaction) para entender quais dispositivos conseguem interpretar esse atributo.

Conforme [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button):

> **formaction:** A URI de um programa que processa a informação submetida
>   pelo botão. Se especificado, ele sobrescreve o atributo action do
>   formulário proprietário do botão.

PS: A aceitação desse atributo no `button` é significativamente maior do que se você utilizar `<input type='submit'>`, conforme [este link](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_htmlinputelement_formaction).

```
<button type='submit' class='btn btn-danger' name='FINALIZAR' value="OK" formaction='/envio1.php'>FINALIZAR</button>
<button type='submit' class='btn btn-success' formaction='/envio2.php'>ALTERAR</button>
```

Comment: Excelente com base na sua resposta fiz aqui e deu certo. Obrigado